# No Product Attributes in Catalog Price Rule Options

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to set up a catalog price rule based on size, but the only options listed for Conditions are Attribute Set and Category.

Is there something I'm missing here, or something I have yet to configure? I know I've been able to do this with other M2 stores. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check if the size attribute is set to be used for Promo rules ?

Comment: Sneaky setting, hidden away. So: no. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your attribute settings and edit the attribute you want to use in a Catalog Promo rule.

On attribute edit page click on **Storefront Properties** tab and select **Yes** for **Use for Promo Rule Conditions**.

I hope this will help.